# Yii force login returning to home page always

Tags: php, authentication, yii2

In my website there is a section to create ad.So i need to force login before creating an ad.
my access control code is like

```
'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['logout','signup','createad','upload','remove'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['signup'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['?'],
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout','createad','upload','remove','update-leads'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
```

This code snippet is forcing the user to login when clicking the create ad button.But after logging in,the user getting redirected to the home page always.I want to redirect to the create ad controller.But my login code looks fine

```
if($model->login())
                return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer);
```

If the user logged in then i need the user to get redirected to the controller where the force login called.How can i do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is common and it is related to the issue that at the time when you post login, your actual referrer is login page - actionLogin(), so you are redirected back again and off course you get passed throughout the condition that you are not the Guest. In order to handle this, you have to assign a referrer to a modal field, so it can be posted with the login information. So at the time when login is validated, you have the required referrer url in your field. Check if you have this field identified in your form:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'login-form']); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'referer')->hiddenInput()->label(false) ?>
```

**Controller**

```
$form = new LoginForm();
//get previos viewed page url and store in the new model
$form->referer = Yii::$app->request->referrer;
if ($form->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
   if($form->login()){
      return $this->goBack((($form->referer) ? $form->referer : null));
   }
}
```

**LoginForm() model**

```
public $referer;
/**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //...
            ['referer', 'string'],
        ];
    }
```

After that, when it will be post request, this field will contain a referrer, which you will pass in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look what is going on:

1. The user access some `/protected-site`, (referer: doesn't matter)
2. The user is redirected to `/login`and the form is displayed, (referer: `/protected-site`)
3. The user submits the form to `/login` (referer: `/login`)
4. The user is logged in and redirected to referer from step 3.

From this you can see that you can't use the referer value for redirecting user back. To where he was before he was sent to login form. For cases like that there is a [`goBack()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-controller#goBack()-detail) method in `yii\web\Controller`. You can use it like this:

```php
if ($model->login()) {
    return $this->goBack();
}
```

This method uses [`yii\web\User::$returnUrl`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-user#$returnUrl-detail) instead of referer. This value is stored in session when the `AccessControl` filter denies the access and redirects user to login action.